# A question on cokernel

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, morita-equivalence

I was reading the proof of Theorem 7.12.11 in the book "Tensor categories" by Etingof et al. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a finite multi-tensor category, and $A$ be an algebra in $\mathcal{C}$. Let $Bimod(A)$ be the category of $A$-$A$-bimodules in $\mathcal{C}$ and $Bimod(A^R \otimes A)$ be the category of $A^R \otimes A$-bimodules in $\mathcal{C}$. Here $A^R$ is the right adjoint of $A$ and the multiplication of the algebra $A^R \otimes A$ is induced by the evaluation $ev: A \otimes A^R \to 1$, $1$ is the tensor unit of $\mathcal{C}$.
It seems that the proof of Theorem 7.12.11 implies that the functor
$$
\mathcal{C} \xrightarrow{\simeq}  Bimod(A^R \otimes A)\ ,\qquad x \mapsto A^R \otimes x \otimes A
$$
is a tensor equivalence of the categories. I know that the functor is fully faithful and essentially surjective. But I do not know how to show that the functor is a monoidal functor. More explicitly, I would like to know how to show that
$$
(A^R \otimes x \otimes A) \otimes_{A^R \otimes A} (A^R \otimes y \otimes A) \simeq A^R \otimes x \otimes y \otimes A,
$$
where $(A^R \otimes x \otimes A) \otimes_{A^R \otimes A} (A^R \otimes y \otimes A)$ is the coequaliser of the morphisms:
$$
1_{A^R \otimes x} \otimes ev \otimes 1_{A \otimes A^R \otimes y \otimes A}
$$
and
$$
1_{A^R \otimes x \otimes A \otimes A^R} \otimes ev \otimes 1_{y \otimes A}
$$

Comment: i guess that "essentially subjective" is "essentially surjective" ?